# Konsole execute a script

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, konsole

```
konsole --noclose -e --rcfile /filepathtomyscript
```

I tried to execute the above commands because i want konsole can execute a list of commands with arguments such as

```
lftp
open...
login
put....
```

However, I keep get errors. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot.
All the examples I found so far just execute a single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
konsole --noclose -e /bin/bash /path/to/my/script
```

[Konsole Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/konsole.1.html)

> -e  [ arguments ]
>
> ```
>           Execute ’command’ instead of shell.  It  also  sets  the  window
>           title  and  icon  name  to  be the basename of the program being
>           executed if neither -T nor -n are given  on  the  command  line.
>           This must be the last option on the command line.
> ```

Comment: When i tried it, i got the warning: Could not start program '...' with arguments '...'. Both of program and arguments are same in warning message.

Comment: warning: could not start program '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/perfTest/input1/simple.sh' with arguments '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/perfTest/input1/simple.sh"

Comment: @HuyNguyen OK I see the problem look at my post.

Comment: OK so what `-e` is looking for is an ELF binary to execute, not a script.

Comment: I am now confused as to what you are looking for.

Comment: i just want to  run a script in terminal. It will open like 4,5 terminal to connect to a ftp server. Each terminal can execute some lftp commands which i put in a script